# Stored Procedure does not use available index on table (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, indexing

A `SELECT` query in my stored procedure takes **3 seconds** to execute when the table queried has no indexes. This is true in **both** when executing the query in *Toad Editor* and when calling the stored procedure. The *Explain Plan* shows that a full table scan is done.

When an index is added, the same query in *Toad Editor* returns results **instantaneously** (just a few milliseconds). The *Explain Plan* shows that the index is used. However, even when the index is present, the query still takes **3 seconds** in the stored procedure. It looks like the query uses a full table scan when executed in stored procedure despite having an index that can speed it up. **Why?**

I have tried with indexes on different columns with different orders. The same results persist in all cases.

In the stored procedure, the results of the query are collected using `BULK COLLECT INTO`. Does this make a difference? **Also,** The stored procedure is inside a package.

The query is a very simple `SELECT` statement, like this:

```
  SELECT MY_COL, COUNT (MY_COL)
    /* this line is only in stored proc */ BULK COLLECT INTO mycollection
    FROM MY_TABLE
   WHERE ANOTHER_COL = '123' /* or ANOTHER_COL = filterval (which is type NUMBER) */
GROUP BY MY_COL
ORDER BY MY_COL
```

Comment: **SHOW** the execution plans after and before adding the index. For more insight, trace the session and post the log details.

Comment: I have already summarized the execution plan results well enough. The question will not gain any additional information from showing the verbose output or other log details. Anyway I have solved the problem already. Also no need to shout `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Without source code we can only guess...

So I suspect it's because in Toad you get just first 500 rows (500 is default buffer size in Toad) but in stored proc you fetch ALL rows into collection. So fetching probably takes most of 3 sec time. Especially if there are nested loops iny our query.

Update: It might also be implicit type conversion in where condition

Comment: No, even in Toad Editor the query takes **3 seconds** to execute with no indexes. And it's just a `SELECT` query, no loops and procedural stuff.

Comment: Can you share your proc source code please? It might also be implicit type conversion in where condition...

Comment: OMG YES! It **is** implicit type conversion. When I changed a condition's filter value from string to number, the query started doing full table scan in *Toad Editor* even with index present. I have added the query in question, please update your answer and I can accept! Silly me, I didn't think of this.

Comment: One small question, would doing `ANOTHER_COL = CAST(filterval as VARCHAR2)` in stored proc work fine and use the index? I can't change the type of filterval to `VARCHAR2`, it has to be `NUMBER`.

Comment: Ignore that. It should be `ANOTHER_COL = TO_CHAR(filterval)`.

Comment: So yes, you've sorted out it by yourself.